# related rate word problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

City planners have decided to develop their city in the shape of a square which increases at three square miles per year. Find the rate of increase of the dimensions of the city when its area is 16 square miles.

My answer was

$$ A = s^2 $$
$$ \frac{da}{dt} = 3$$

$$ \frac{da}{dt}a = 2s \frac{ds}{dt} $$
$$ (3)(16) = 2(4)\frac{ds}{dt} $$

$$ \frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{3 \cdot 16}{2 \cdot 4} = 6 $$

but the answer in the books is $ \frac{8}{3} $ so what am i missing here ?
Isn't by dimensions he means the sides of the squares ?

Comment: Do you mean the square's area increases at that rate?

Comment: The question says i need to find the rate of which the dimensions of the square increase by when the area of the square is 16.